# How can I proper use flatMap in a hierarchical Map<String, MyData>?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I have a `Map<String, MyData>` and the`MyData`object contains a `properties` attribute that is also of `Map<String, MyData>` type.

I need to traverse this model, looking for a specific MyData object and return its key.

I've tried to construct a flatmap like the one below, but it is not working... somehow the result of the flatmap is a `Stream<Object>` instead of `Stream<Entry<String, MyData>>`

Could someone point me what I'm doing wrong, please?

```
public class MyData<S> {
  private String name;
  private Map<String, MyData> properties;
  ...
}
```

```
MyData target = ...;

String key = getAllData().entrySet().stream()
  .flatMap(s -> s.getValue().getProperties().entrySet().stream())
  .filter(e-> target == e.getValue())
              .findFirst()
              .map(o-> o.getKey())
              .orElse("not found");
```

Comment: I can run the code with jdk 11, assuming `s.getValue().getProperties()` type is `Map<String, MyData>`.

Comment: @samabcde, really? this is odd. I'm also running java 11 with eclipse and I'm getting `The method getValue() is undefined for the type Object` :(

Comment: Please also include `MyData` class to make sure I didn't missing anything.

Comment: ok, I've added it.

Comment: Oh MyData is generic, then it is probably due to you are using raw type. Can you add `<?>` to those `MyData` type?

Comment: Yep, its generic and the getProperties() is using raw type. I cannot change MyData class, unfortunately. :(

Comment: I think I managed to trick the compiler. I've created a method passing and returning `Stream<Entry<String, MyData>>` and use it in the flatMap. Going to test the result now.

Comment: It seems rather that the return type of `getAllData()` is the problem. Note that you don’t need to iterate over `entrySet()` when you never use the key. Using `values()` in the first place allows you to use a function that redeclares the type to be non-raw: `getAllData().values().stream() .flatMap( (MyData<?> d) -> d.getProperties().entrySet().stream()) .filter(e-> target == e.getValue()) .map(Map.Entry::getKey) .findFirst() .orElse("not found")`

Comment: Wouldn't this result in an infinite loop? You flatmap the contents of MyData's stream which has more MyData objects contained within it.

Comment: @J.Lengel, I think that the filter I'm using prevents an infinite loop. At least I didn't have received ant StackOverflow yet. :)

Comment: Oh ok. Just making some observations :)